# I want to display only 4 items of td and then start a new tr with another 4 items

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<table class='listing'>"; 
$i=0;
for ($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++) {
       while( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='?p=view_org&oid={$row['org_id']}'>{$row['org_name']}<br /><img src='{$row['org_logo']}' width='120px' /></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";  
    }
echo "</table>";
```

The result is produced with one tr and td so the image is shown as a list... can anyone give any idea to process this loop to have only 4 items of td and then start a new tr with another 4 items?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to combine styling with server-side code. Render all your images using `<ul>` and `<li>`, then use CSS to specify how many images per row.

Comment: even tho its not excatly what you asked, i vote for answer @NightHawk  commented. Its best practice to let CSS handle that ^^

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "<table class='listing'><tr>";
$i = 0;
while( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "<td><a href='?p=view_org&oid={$row['org_id']}'>{$row['org_name']}<br /><img src='{$row['org_logo']}' width='120px' /></a></td>";
    $i++;
    if($i%4==0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
echo "<table class='listing'>"; 
$i=0;
echo "<tr>";   
     while( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {         
     echo "<td><a href='?p=view_org&oid={$row['org_id']}'>{$row['org_name']}<br /><img src='{$row['org_logo']}' width='120px' /></a></td>";
     $i++; 
     if($i%4==0)
         echo "</tr><tr>";               
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: try with `$i++` before the `if` otherwise it will print `</tr><tr>` right after first element

Comment: Ya i edited that one,instantly i didnt notice for the first loop when $i=0,and you @Mihai lorga,every time you are answering just even 20 sec faster than me..

Answer (score 0):

User array function : array_chunk();

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$t = array_chunk($input_array, 4);

It will give output like this : 

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
        [3] => d        

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => e
    )

)
```

you can use for / foreach loop :

```
<table>

for($i ; $< count($t); $i++)
{
    <tr>

         for($j = 0 ; $j < 4 ; $j++) 
         {
             <td>echo $t[$i][$j];</td>
         }

    </tr>
}
</table>
```